Cannot find org.w3c.dom classes in JDK 21 in Eclipse 2024-03
Ant can build our jar file with no problem, but Eclipse using the same class path complains that org.w3c.dom.Document cannot be resolved. If I drop those source files in my src tree it complains that org.w3s.dom already exists in java.xml.
The project was not built since its build 
path is incomplete. Cannot find the class 
file for org.w3c.dom.Document. Fix the build 
path then try building this project
The type org.w3c.dom.Document cannot be 
resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type 
org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser



Closing and Opening my project did not fix this bug.

Do you have an [mcve] for this? Also, have you searched for others with the same or similar problem on the web already?

Is your Ant build also using Java 21?

What is the exact error message, and are you using Java Modules?

This sounds like you have a module-info.java file without the required  requires ...; statement for the module containing the org.w3c.dom package. So either add the missing  requires ...; statement or delete your module-info.java file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-clicking on project and choosing Configure).

Ant and Eclipse are using: OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_21.0.3_9
There is no module-info.java in:  C:\cypress\Java\jdk-21.0.3.9\lib\src.zip\ 
or in my project.

Adding xmlbeans-2.3.0 to our poi ivy file caused the problem to show up for me but not my boss who has the same levels of everything.

The errors: Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.w3c.dom.Document. Fix the build path then try building this project J21_cypress-webapp  Unknown Java Problem
The type org.w3c.dom.Document cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser CypressCriteriaHelper.java /J21_cypress-webapp/src/java/com/pinales/cypress/helper/criteria line 77 Java Problem

Please edit your question and add the error message formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). Please tell exactly which JAR contains org.w3c.dom.Document and how you add the JAR to Project > Properties: Java Build Path, tab Libraries.

NO jar contains org.w3c.dom.Document, it's supposed to find it in the Java 21 module but IT DOES NOT SEE IT THERE unless I manually add the org.w3c.dom SOURCE FILES to my code tree and then it complains of a duplicate package which makes no sense.

In Java 9 and higher, the system library consists of modules. In addition, each JAR on the modulepath is a module of its own and everything else is handled as the unnamed module. For example, a package in your code or in a dependency that also exists in the system library is illegal. org.w3c.dom.Document is in the java.xml module of the system library. In the Package or Projects Explorer, do you see below the project folder the node JRE System Library [JavaSE-21]?
